# Using asyncio in the middle of Python3.6 script

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a Python task that reports on it's progress during execution using a status updater that has 1 or more handlers associated with it. I want the updates to be dispatched to each handler in an asynchronous way (each handler is responsible for making an I/O bound call with the updates, pushing to a queue, logging to a file, calling a HTTP endpoint etc). The status updater has a method like so with each `handler.dispatch` method being a coroutine. This was working until a handler using aiohttp was added and now I am getting weird errors from the aiohttp module.

```py
def _dispatch(self, **updates):
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = (event_loop.create_task(handler.dispatch(**updates)) for handler in self._handlers)
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

Every example of asyncio I've seen basically has this pattern

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

My question is, is the way I am attempting to use the asyncio module in this case just completely wrong? Does the event loop need to be created once and only once and then everything else goes through that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you hope `_dispatch` will do. `event_loop.run_until_complete` blocks the thread, so you won't get other things outside the event loop happening while it is running.

Comment: Yep I'm aware, i simpy want to make 1 or more I/O bound calls asynchrously. Pushing the updates to a queue, logging to a file, calling a http endpoint etc.